# How to do a dynamic search using multiple attributes in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a user table with following attributes:

- FirstName
- LastName
- City
- CompanyName

I want to query the table with any combination of these attributes and that too partial .

For example:
Input - Firstname- "bh" and lastname - "ta"
Output -A Record with FirstName "aBHishek" , lastName"gupTA"

How do I do this query without using scan?
Does using scanconditions with contains means the read operation is less costly?

I have tried this in C#:

```
var conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
{
    var firstName = new ScanCondition("SearchFirstName", ScanOperator.Contains, user.FirstName.ToLower());
    conditions.Add(firstName);
}
 

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
{
    var lastName = new ScanCondition("SearchLastName", ScanOperator.Contains, user.LastName.ToLower());
     conditions.Add(lastName);
}

var allUsers = await _context.ScanAsync<OpenOrderUser>(conditions).GetRemainingAsync();
return allUsers;
```

it does the trick but I want to move away from Scan and use Query, any suggestions? is this approach optimal?

Comment: What's the key schema of the table? Do you need partial matches on all listed attributes or just first/last name?

Comment: Right , I need partial matches on all the listed attributes , it could be any combination.

Comment: You can't achieve that in the general case without scan and filter.

Comment: so the approach I have above is the only way? Do the ScanConditions limit the scan of whole table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option you have to retrieve data from an Amazon DynamoDB table when using the AWS SDK for .NET V3 is to use PartiQL. This lets you use **SELECT** statements to retrieve data from a table in Amazon DynamoDB. Its similiar to SQL.

You can read more here:

[PartiQL select statements for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html)

YOu can find full .NET Code example here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/dotnetv3/dynamodb/scenarios/PartiQL_Basics_Scenario/PartiQL_Basics_Scenario/PartiQLMethods.cs

Comment: Interesting , I am looking into this more and will try it out

Comment: Be aware that your PartiQL queries are simply going to be converted into the relevant DynamoDB query/scan calls under the covers. It doesn't release you from the obligation to plan your queries and table schema in advance to ensure efficient and performant queries.

Comment: you are right , its very tricky with PartiQL as well , without a proper where condition, it still treats it as a scan.